# Import issue in react admin

Tags: react-admin

I have imported Password input is given below

```js
import { PasswordInput } from 'react-admin';
```

My Working React admin code is given below,

```js
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React admin
            </a>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

I have imported Password input. but getting error. failed to compile. How to fix this issue

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the error you've got ?

Comment: And would you please add the code where this `PasswordInput` is used?